# prove that mixing time of direct random walk on a finite group is uniform

Tags: group-theory, random-walk

Let $W=(G,S,P)$ be a directed random walk. Then the probability distribution $Q^k(g)$ tends to uniform stationary distribution $\pi(g)=\frac{1}{|G|}$ as $k$ tends to infinity.

Consider an element $g=s_1s_2...s_k \in G$, where $k$ is as small as possible. Then the probability of getting to $g$ starting from the identity element in $n$ steps can be calculated in two cases: Suppose $n>k$.

Here then probability of reaching to $g$ is $P(s_1)P(s_2)...P(s_k)*EE$  where $EE$ is the probability to reaching $e$ in $n-k$ steps starting at $e$.

we essentially need to prove that $EE$ equals to $\frac{1}{|G|*P(s_1)P(s_2)...P(s_k)}$ Because then when plugging this in the place of $EE$ we'll get that $Q^k(g)$ tends to uniform distribution. Now I'm stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convergence to Uniform Distribution of a Random Walk on a Finite Group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2777057/convergence-to-uniform-distribution-of-a-random-walk-on-a-finite-group)